# What is the difference among Visual Studio Express edition, microsoft.net and VS professional edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Could anyone guide me as what is the difference among the following,
1) Visual Studio Express Edition
2)Visual Studio Professioanl Edition
3) Microsoft .Net 
And is there any thing like Visual Studio.Net?

Please guide me, as I am currently working on express edition, but my other colleaques are working on different environment which I don't know (language is same for all developers i.e. VB), and I need to do some working on their implemented codes as well.

Please guide me,

Regards
Asad

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Supported_products    has a nice graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Microsoft .NET" is a platform rather than an IDE. It's not really comparable with the other two.

The Express editions of Visual Studio are basically cut down versions of the commercial editions. In particular, Express doesn't allow plug-ins such as ReSharper to run - but there are various other limitations too. If you're a professional software developer, you should almost certainly ask your company to provide you with VS Professional (or higher, but Pro will probably be fine). You certainly *can* develop in Express, but it's really designed for hobbyists rather than professional developers.

Visual Studio was called Visual Studio .NET just for two releases - 2002 and 2003.

Comment: Yes, i have recently started career in development domain. My other colleqeas are using Professional edition, but i am using express one, alhtough i have the liscensed for me as well for professional edition.

Comment: @Asad: If you've got a licence for Professional then I strongly suggest you install that.

Comment: what do you mean by Platform, than an IDE(as i know what an IDE is, but i donot know  what a platform meant?).

Comment: my colleaque forwarded me a code of VB but i am unable to open it with espress edition.

Comment: All the files have .FRM and .FRX and .BAS extension.

Comment: @Asad: That sounds like it's possibly VB6 rather than VB.NET. Find out *exactly* which version of Visual Studio they're using.

Comment: but please highlight the difference between plateform(.net) and IDE(VS)?

Comment: @Asad: In this case, ".NET" is a combination of libraries and the runtime (CLR). Collectively it provides everything you need when you're *running* the application. It also contains C# and VB compilers, so you *can* develop with just .NET installed, but usually having an IDE is worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks Jon you are really helpfull~

Comment: Just confirmed fro colleaque thast the project forwarded to me was in VB 6.0.Please tell me any method to compile,execute this VB6 code in VS 2010(Express Edition)

Comment: @Asad: You can't. You'll need VB6. As of Visual Studio .NET 2002, Visual Studio doesn't support VB "classic".

Answer (score 0):

The .Net framework is a collection of libraries.
Visual Studio Professional is the paid edition of Visual Studio Express.
There is also a Standard Edition which has less functionality than the Pro version.

One difference between Express and Pro is that the Pro Edition has the possibility to connect to a database (like SQL Manager studio)

Comment: Note that VS2010 doesn't have a Standard SKU - just Professional, Premium and Ultimate.

Comment: So you mean Visual studion uses the libraries of .Net framework?

Comment: which software i need to install to open .FRM , .FRX and .BAS files of VB project?

Comment: @ Asad: yes, you are using functions in the libraries while programming in Visual Studio. The reason you can not open these files is because you have installed the C# Express edition. If you switch to the Pro version make sure you both install C# and VB.